# Convert indefinite integrals to definite integrals and evaluate inside an expression in Maxima

Tags: differential-equations, maxima

I am trying to solve a 1st order ODE in Maxima (namely wxMaxima). From `ode2`, I obtain an expression that contains indefinite integrals, which I want to be evaluated at limits I define, namely `(0,t)`.

```
pta: 'diff(q,t)+(1/taub)*q = 1/(c0+c1)*'diff(Q,t)+1/(c0*taub)*Q;
Qproblem: (Q1/t1)*t;
ptap: ev(pta,Q=Qproblem);
assume(t1>0, Q1>0, t>0);
sol: ode2(ptap,q,t);
grind(sol);
```

If I apply `grind` on the solution expression, I get the following

```
q = %e^-(t/taub)*((c0*t1*taub*'integrate(%e^(t/taub)*'diff(t*Q1/t1,t,1),t)
                 +c1*(t*taub-taub^2)*%e^(t/taub)*Q1
                 +c0*(t*taub-taub^2)*%e^(t/taub)*Q1)
                 /((c0*c1+c0^2)*t1*taub)
                 +%c)$
```

This expression cannot be evaluated correctly unless those integrals turn into definite ones. Hence I wanto to convert them somehow. I mentioned the desired limits above.

What kind of approach should I use? Is there a flag to `ode2` I am not aware of that helps with this? Or is there a function that can extract and replace parts from an expression, so that I can add 2 more parameters to the `'integrate`s while still retaining the first parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate `ev(sol, nouns)` to tell Maxima to evaluate the `'integrate` and `'diff` nouns. After that try `ratsimp` to simplify the result.